# Losing characters over socket in string

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcplistener

I'm sending a message over a socket.
On the client side i'm assembling the message using StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message);
sb.Insert(0, (char)11);
sb.Append((char)28);
sb.Append((char)13);
```

Sending it from client to server

```
Byte[] data = new Byte[1024];
data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message.ToString());
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Server Side

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytesReceived.Length));
```

I then want to check to see if my message is contained within the correct container but for some reason the last 2 characters equal 0 in the check instead of the correct 28 and 13.

```
if (((int)messsage[message.Length - 2] == 28) && ((int)message[message.Length - 1] == 13))
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Added Data that was asked for

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: What's the value of `bytesReceived.Length`? Can you also show the code you use to read the bytes.

Comment: It's likely that you are making a call to read the data from the client, giving it an amount of bytes to read, and it's not reading them all. The read calls may return a shorter number of bytes than you ask for, you then need to to detect this and ask for more. As ChrisF has asked, we need to see your code that reads from the network stream

Comment: Look at the return value of stream.Read()... that tells you how many bytes were actually read

Comment: Your code here indicates that you are building your tweaked message in a StringBuilder called sb, but you appear to be sending the original message variable. Do you set message equal to sb.ToString() outside the code you show here or did you mean to use sb.ToString() rather than message.ToString()?

Comment: I have added the extra code that was asked for and i'm sure that's where the problem is. The data being sent, it's length will vary so I'm guessing I can't declare it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stream.Read` will read up to `bytes.Length` bytes, it's return value will tell you how many bytes it actually read.

If that is not enough, then you will need to call `Stream.Read()` again.

Also, `bytes.Length` will always return the length of the array, not the number of bytes read.

Looking at your sending code, you probably want to read as much as you can from the stream, append what was read to the string builder, then check to see if the last 2 characters are 28 and 13, and if they are then you have your complete message.

Comment: Much thanks for the input. I have corrected the issue I was having.

     do
     {
         bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         completeMessage.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0,  bytesRead));
         }
         while (stream.DataAvailable);